# Tracking the progress of a drag event while running. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to track the value to the position of the mouse while the drag event is still running and if the value is so and so then execute some code code?

Edit: Since this confuses people. I am looking for a way to get real time data of the position of the mouse while dragging. By real time I mean finding the position of the mouse while dragging not on drag beginning or end.

Comment: Which kind of drag event? The kind that involves the clipboard or the other???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use `setOnMouseDragged();`:

```
source.setOnMouseDragged(m->{
            System.out.println("MouseScreenX:"+m.getScreenX()+", MouseScreenY:"+m.getScreenY());
            System.out.println("MouseSceneX:"+m.getSceneX()+", MouseSceneY:"+m.getSceneY());

            //Execute some code here(maybe it has to run in a different Thread)
            //....code
            //....
        });
```

> In case you are not comfortable with [lambda expressions](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html):

```
source.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("MouseScreenX:" + event.getScreenX() + ", MouseScreenY:" + event.getScreenY());
                System.out.println("MouseSceneX:" + event.getSceneX() + ", MouseSceneY:" + event.getSceneY());

                // Execute some code here(maybe it has to run in a different
                // Thread)
                // ...code
                // ....
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm looking for real time data not on mouse dragged.

Comment: @Adam Ren What you mean real time data?Describe it cause nobody will gonna understand.The folder on which the mouse is over?The Window?

Comment: I need to see where is mouse is while it's dragging not while finished our beginning.

Comment: What I mean is I am looking for the position of the mouse between the beginning and end of the mouse event. `setOnMouseDragged` as far as I understand runs when the program determines the you are dragging and not clicking. While on released of course is when the drag ends. Correct? I want to know if there is an event that finds where the mouse is while your still moving the mouse.

Comment: @AdamRen Why don't you just test it and see? `setOnMouseDragged` is invoked on every pulse if the mouse has been dragged (any non-zero distance, no matter how small) since the last pulse. I.e. it is invoked during dragging, not just at the beginning and end.

Comment: @James_D Then I got it's function confused then. Probably was mixing it up with onDragDetected...

Comment: @James_D I see a strange behavior where i attach the `setOnMouseDragged()` to a `Rectangle` and then i drag into the `Rectangle` and outside but it reports `println()` only about 2-3 times and then nothing.Also same with `setOnMouseMoved()`,from the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_DRAGGED it seems that it is normal? I mean i want as long as i drag the mouse to report the position of the mouse on Screen.

Comment: @Adam Ren Edited the Answer.

Comment: @AdamRen Sounds like you are dragging outside the rectangle without setting it up to do so. Recommend you  read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To execute some code while being in the drag process:

```
setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEventevent) {
            //your code here 
        }
    });
```

what exactly do you mean with "and if the value is so and so then execute some code code?"?